# Create vector selecting values from two different vectors

Tags: r

Currently, this code works to do what I want to do where dx$res is a vector selecting values from dx$val1 or dx$val2 depending on value of dx$x0.

```
x0<-c(1,2,1,2,2,1)
val1<-c(8,6,4,5,3,2)
val2<-c(4,8,6,7,9,5)
dx<-data.frame(x0,val1,val2)
dx$res<-(dx$x0==1)*dx$val1+(dx$x0==2)*dx$val2
```

I would like to know if there were more elegant methods to do this like using apply function.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `with`: `dx$res <- with(dx, (x0 == 1) * val1 + (x0 == 2) * val2)`. It's probably easier to read. there is also an `ifelse` solution, but I prefer the method that you used.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `model.matrix` with `rowSums`.  It is also more general for 'n' number of distinct elements in the 'x0' column.

```
dx$res <- rowSums(dx[-1]*model.matrix(~ factor(x0) - 1 , dx))
dx$res
#[1] 8 8 4 7 9 2
```